# Task is scheduled and waiting to run but never executed

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I am new to asynchronous programming in C# and I'm having issues with some async methods. Those methods communicate with an external Bluetooth motion sensor. The problem is that, in some rare cases, the same method waits for a task that is never ran.

The situation is in the image below. The task *MBientLab.MetaWear.Impl.MetaWearBoard.createRouteAsync()* waits for the scheduled task to complete. So that task must be started from within the *MBientLab.MetaWear.Impl.MetaWearBoard.createRouteAsync()* task, which is part of the used API.

[image: Currently running tasks]

So as we can see, the highlighted line is a task that is scheduled and waiting to run, but it remains in that state no matter how long I wait. It never gets into active state. The other tasks are waiting for the highlighted task to complete, so everything is stuck.

Can this be a deadlock, or could it be that the task waiting for something that will never complete? I'm a bit confused and I don't know how to approach this problem.

EDIT: I extracted the code that causes the problems. It needs the nuggets from the *using* statements, Windows SDK and the sensor to work. So you probably won't be able to run it, but maybe there are some obvious mistakes.

```
// Nuggets
using MbientLab.MetaWear;
using MbientLab.MetaWear.Core;
using MbientLab.MetaWear.Data;
using MbientLab.MetaWear.Sensor;
using MbientLab.MetaWear.Win10;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth;

namespace MBientLabSensor
{
    public class MotionSensor
    {
        public List<double> GetX { get; } = new List<double>();
        public List<double> GetY { get; } = new List<double>();
        public List<double> GetZ { get; } = new List<double>();

        IMetaWearBoard _metawearDevice = null;

        // List of Bluetooth devices found after scanning
        private List<BluetoothLEDevice> DeviceList = new List<BluetoothLEDevice>();

        public async Task Connect(string MAC, int retries = 1)
        {
            if (_metawearDevice != null)
            {
                await StopAndDisconnectMotionSensor();
            }

            await ConnectToSensor(MAC.Trim(), retries);
        }

        public async Task StopAndDisconnectMotionSensor()
        {
            StopAccelerometer(_metawearDevice);
            await Disconnect(_metawearDevice);
        }

        public void StopAccelerometer(IMetaWearBoard _metawearDevice)
        {
            if (_metawearDevice == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("The provided device is null!");
            }

            var acc = _metawearDevice.GetModule<IAccelerometer>();
            // Put accelerometer back into standby mode
            acc.Stop();
            // Stop accelerationi data
            acc.Acceleration.Stop();
        }

        public async virtual Task Disconnect(IMetaWearBoard _metawearDevice)
        {
            if (_metawearDevice == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("The MetaWear device instance is null!");
            }

            _metawearDevice.TearDown();

            // Have the board terminate the BLE connection
            await _metawearDevice.GetModule<IDebug>().DisconnectAsync();
        }

        public async Task ConnectToSensor(string MAC, int retries = 3)
        {
            BluetoothLEDevice device = DeviceList.Find(x => ConvertToMAC(x.BluetoothAddress).Trim() == MAC.Trim());
            await AttemptConnect(device, retries);
        }

        private async Task AttemptConnect(BluetoothLEDevice BLEDevice, int retries)
        {
            _metawearDevice = await ConnectToDevice(BLEDevice, retries);

            if (_metawearDevice != null)
            {
                Task task = Task.Run(async () => await Setup(_metawearDevice));
                SetAccSamplingRate(_metawearDevice, 100f, 16f);
                StartAcc(_metawearDevice);
            }
        }

        public async Task Setup(IMetaWearBoard device, float connInterval = 7.5f)
        {
            if (device == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("The provided device is null!");
            }

            // Set the connection interval
            await SetBLEConnectionInterval(device, connInterval);
            var acc = device.GetModule<IAccelerometer>();

            // Use data route framework to tell the MetaMotion to stream accelerometer data to the host device
            await acc.Acceleration.AddRouteAsync(source => source.Stream(data =>
            {
                // Clear buffers if there is too much data inside them
                if (GetX.Count > 1000)
                {
                    ClearSensorData();
                }

                // Buffer received data
                GetX.Add(data.Value<Acceleration>().X);
                GetY.Add(data.Value<Acceleration>().Y);
                GetZ.Add(data.Value<Acceleration>().Z);
            }));
        }

        public void ClearSensorData()
        {
            GetX.Clear();
            GetY.Clear();
            GetZ.Clear();
        }

        private async Task SetBLEConnectionInterval(IMetaWearBoard device, float maxConnInterval = 7.5f)
        {
            if (device == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("The provided device is null!");
            }

            // Adjust the max connection interval
            device.GetModule<ISettings>()?.EditBleConnParams(maxConnInterval: maxConnInterval);
            await Task.Delay(1500);
        }

        public void SetAccSamplingRate(IMetaWearBoard device, float samplingRate = 100f, float dataRange = 16f)
        {
            if (device == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("The provided device is null!");
            }

            var acc = device.GetModule<IAccelerometer>();
            // Set the data rate and data to the specified values or closest valid values
            acc.Configure(odr: samplingRate, range: dataRange);
        }

        public void StartAcc(IMetaWearBoard device)
        {
            if (device == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("The provided device is null!");
            }

            var acc = device.GetModule<MbientLab.MetaWear.Sensor.IAccelerometer>();
            // Start the acceleration data
            acc.Acceleration.Start();
            // Put accelerometer in active mode
            acc.Start();
        }

        public async virtual Task<IMetaWearBoard> ConnectToDevice(BluetoothLEDevice device, int retries = 1)
        {
            _metawearDevice = Application.GetMetaWearBoard(device);

            if (_metawearDevice == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("The MetaWear device is null!");
            }

            // How long the API should wait (in milliseconds) before a required response is received
            _metawearDevice.TimeForResponse = 5000;

            int x = retries;

            do
            {
                try
                {
                    await _metawearDevice.InitializeAsync();
                    retries = -1;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    retries--;
                }
            } while (retries > 0);

            if (retries == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return _metawearDevice;
            }
        }

        private string ConvertToMAC(ulong value)
        {
            string hexString = value.ToString("X");
            // Pad the hex string with zeros on the left until 12 nibbles (6 bytes) are present
            hexString = hexString.PadLeft(12, '0');
            return hexString.Insert(2, ":").Insert(5, ":").Insert(8, ":").Insert(11, ":").Insert(14, ":");
        }
    }
}
```

I ran it using

```
Task.Run(async () => await Connect(MAC, 3));
```

Comment: Can you please show the corresponding code? Without code it's not possible to give you the exact reason and solution as it could be everything. In general, it would be nice if posted code compiles and executes to help others to reproduce the error. Code tells so much more than a screenshot of an error message or random debugger window...

Comment: `you probably won't be able to run it` - Simplify the code one part at a time, e.g., by using `await Task.Delay(500)` instead of real asynchronous work, and testing it after each simplification. Eventually, you will either reduce it to something that *can* be run by everyone (if all external dependencies have been removed), or you will find exactly the part of the code that isn't working right (if it starts working, then the last simplification will point you to the problem).

Answer (score 1):

`Task.Run()` wraps your code into the `Task`. The Task is being executed but you need to capture the result of Task execution. So you need to do this:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () => await Connect(MAC, 3));

await task;
```

But there is no sense to do this. If you want to await your async operation, simply do this:

```
await Connect(Mac, 3)
```